# How to design 3D effect in widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is any way to make 3D effect in widget ?
I have tried with Container and shadow with blur effect but it does not worked. How to make like below image frame?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try using PhysicalModel widget.